# Critique request: three 筹备 sentences: 有的人的筹备很不合理 and 北京花了很长时间做筹备工作 and 不需要筹备任何配料

Tags: writing-critique

(*Update*: There was a typo: 之间 should be 时间.  I corrected it.)

I wrote these sentences to practice using [筹备](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%AD%B9%E5%A4%87) instead of [准备](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%87%86%E5%A4%87) which I'm more familiar with.

> 脱欧后，有的人的**筹备**很不合理！
>
> 北京花了很长时间做**筹备**工作，不过因为[冠状病毒](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%86%A0%E7%8A%B6%E7%97%85%E6%AF%92)的发现，政府推迟新年的庆祝。
>
> 西红柿炒鸡蛋是个很简单的菜，不需要**筹备**任何配料。

I'm seeking a critique of these sentences.  I've basically mastered HSK4 and am working on HSK5 now.  I'm particularly interested in what would happen if we replace 筹备 with 准备.

(I refrain from giving an English translation, as it seems to confuse people more than it helps.)

Comment: NB. Eliminating the subtitle makes the title vague, whereas with an extended title, it is possible to judge the question's content from the title alone.  This way, a reader can make a reasonable guess if they'll learn something before clicking.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences sound weird.

Barring other grammatical errors, 筹备 is used to describe “collate resources to prepare for an event”.

> 日本政府已经花了好几年的时间来筹备今年的东京奥运会。

The Japanese Government has spent a few years preparing for the Tokyo Olympics this year.

Your first and third sentences don’t sound right because they don’t refer to an “event” per se, and you should state clearly that the Beijing government was preparing for the New Year celebrations in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in bold:

1. **有人对于**脱欧后**在英国的生活感到迷芒**。
   There are people who are not very well prepared for the post-Brexit world.
2. 北京花了很长**时**间做筹备工作，
   Beijing spent a lot of time getting ready,
   不过因为冠状病毒的出现，
   but, because of the appearance of the corona virus
   政府推迟了新年的庆祝。
   the government postponed the New Year celebrations.
3. 西红柿炒鸡蛋是个很简单的菜，
   Eggs and tomatoes is a very simple dish,
   不需要**准备太多的**配料。
   you don't need to prepare many ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker,

> 脱欧后，有的人的筹备很不合理！

What does it mean?

> 北京花了很长之间做筹备工作，不过因为冠状病毒的发现，政府推迟新年的庆祝。
>
> 西红柿炒鸡蛋是个很简单的菜，不需要筹备任何配料。

In those sentences,it is okay no matter you use "筹备" or "准备".
Actually,we always use "准备" in our daily life.

It seems that there are few circumstances to use "筹备" although "筹备" is more rigorous.(Maybe "准备" reads more smoothly than "筹备"?)

Comment: Thanks!  To answer the question, it's intended to mean: *Post-Brexit, some people's preparations are irrational.*